# Unexpected ";" , expecting ")" near class handle

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, modelsim, hardware

So, I created my first system Verilog testbench by modifying the tutorial from `https://verificationguide.com/systemverilog-examples/systemverilog-testbench-example-01/` ( In this tutorial a memory block is tested, I modified it for a simple AND gate).

There are seven files excluding the DUT file,

1. environment.sv
2. interface.sv
3. transactions.sv
4. generator.sv
5. testbench.sv ( topLevel testbench)
6. driver.sv
7. test.sv

I used Intel modelsim to compile these files.

While compiling, I got these errors in driver.sv and generator.sv

`** Error: (vlog-13069) D:/Altera/Projects/AndGate/testbench/driver.sv(28): near ";": syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting '('.`

`** Error: (vlog-13069) D:/Altera/Projects/AndGate/testbench/generator.sv(4): near "trans": syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting ';' or ','.`

Below are the corresponding files,

**driver.sv**

```
`define DRIV_IF mem_vif.DRIVER.driver_cb

class driver;

    int num_trans;
    virtual mem_intf mem_vif;
    
    mailbox gen2driv;
    
    function new(virtual mem_intf mem_vif, mailbox gen2driv);
        this.mem_vif = mem_vif;
        this.gen2driv = gen2driv;
    endfunction
    task reset();
      wait(mem_vif.reset);
      $display("--------- [DRIVER] Reset Started ---------");
      `DRIV_IF.A <= 0;
      `DRIV_IF.B <= 0;
      `DRIV_IF.C  <= 0;      
      wait(!mem_vif.reset);
      $display("--------- [DRIVER] Reset Ended ---------");
    endtask
    
    
    task drive();

            transaction trans;
            gen2driv.get(trans);
            $display("Num transactions : %0d", num_trans);
            @(posedge mem_vif.DRIVER.clk);
                `DRIV_IF.A <= trans.A;
                `DRIV_IF.B <= trans.B;
                 trans.C = `DRIV_IF.C;
                $display("\tA = %0h \tB = %0h \tC = %0h", trans.A, trans.B, `DRIV_IF.C);
                num_trans++;

    endtask
                
    

endclass
```

**generator.sv**

```
class generator;

    var rand transaction trans;
    mailbox gen2driv;
    int repeat_count;
    event ended;
    
    function new(mailbox gen2driv, event ended);
        this.gen2driv = gen2driv;
        this.ended = ended;
    endfunction
    
    task main();
        repeat(repeat_count) begin
            trans = new();
            if(!trans.randomize())$fatal("Random Generation failed");
            gen2driv.put(trans);

        end
        -> ended;
    endtask

endclass
```

Please, help me with this...

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, it would really help to point to the line 28 and 4 in the respective files where the error is occurring as well as give the command line used to compile the code. But since I've seen this exact error before, I know it is because you put all of these files separately on your command line and not compiled together as a package.

Modelsim/Questa compiles every SystemVerilog file on the command line as a separate compilation unit. Identifiers declared in one compilation unit cannot be seen by other compilation units. When the generator and driver classes get compiled, it has no idea what `transaction` means and you get a syntax error. Modules and interfaces names exist in a separate namespace and the syntax where they are referenced allows them to used before their declarations have been compiled.

To remedy this, you could `` `include `` all you class files in testbench module, or the normal practice is putting them all in a `package` and importing the package. There is also a compilation mode where everything on the command line in one compilation unit, but that option is not scaleable as your designer get larger.

I also suggest reading these two posts I wrote:

https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2010/07/13/package-import-versus-include/

https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2009/05/07/programblocks/